# Remove char on each elements of list

Tags: vb.net

I have a list as below. The list contains `n` elements. I would like to clear each element of the list removing the `"["` or `"]"` char

```vb
Dim bracList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)({"[1_1,2,3", "", "]"})

For i As Integer = 0 To bracList.Count -1
   bracList(i) = bracList(i).Replace("[","").Replace("]","")
Next i
```

The above code works for small list but if I have a big list it takes too long.

Comment: Try to use dictionary except generic list and let me know if it helped with speedo, dictionary is much faster than list or array.. tested

Comment: You may or may not be able to get a small speed increase with [`Regex.Replace(bracList(i), "\[|\]", "")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_), but otherwise there is not much to do.

Comment: Is it the size of the string's in the list or the list itself?

Comment: Can you clean the source of the List? What GSerg proposed can be spiced with `RegexOptions.Compiled` if you have, for example, a large text as source and search for matches on that source.

Comment: If you cannot perform the change on the source, it could be done while adding the items to the List, using a StringBuilder as a temporary container while parsing/rebuilding the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, using regular expressions will result in a significant performance improvement, especially for large lists. You could also use Parallel.Foreach. I don't know how much faster it will be in this case, but theoretically it should be faster:

```
Dim bracList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)({"[1_1,2,3", "", "]"})
Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(bracList, Sub(item)
                                                   item.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")
                                               End Sub)
```